# using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with multiple same bind arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I create the following procedure

```
create or replace procedure check_exec_imm(
tab IN VARCHAR2,
col IN VARCHAR2,
col_name IN VARCHAR2

)

IS

 cv  SYS_REFCURSOR;
 col_value  VARCHAR2(32767);
 lv_query VARCHAR2(32767); 

 BEGIN
   lv_query := 'SELECT ' ||col||
           ' FROM ' ||tab||
           ' WHERE (:1 = ''EUR'' OR :1 = ''USD'') and rownum <=1';


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query INTO col_value USING  col_name ;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN VALUE : ' || col_value);

END;
```

When the procedure is executed, I'm getting the following error

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at "GRM_IV.CHECK_EXEC_IMM", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

When I give the bind argument col_name again as below, the procedure is running fine.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query INTO col_value USING  col_name, col_name ;
```

Why oracle is behaving differently in this procedure. Since, it is the same bind variable, one bind argument should be sufficient right..!!? Please explain where I'm getting my logic wrong.

Comment: `When I give the bind argument col_name again` Yes, you have to provide the same variable twice. Besides identifiers, e.g. column names or table names, cannot be bound, only literals. So this `WHERE (:1 = ''EUR'' OR :1 = ''USD'')` seems not quite correct - instead of identifier a character literal will be used.

Comment: @ Nicholas I've written this procedure to check with multiple same bind arguments. Because, in another procedure while I used another same bind variable multiple times, the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` was working fine. is there  a way that it can be done. I couldn't find out the difference.

Comment: Your logic is correct but it's just not the way it works in Oracle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is "special" behaviour in Oracle: [Repeated Placeholder Names in Dynamic SQL Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01108)

In an Anonymous Block or CALL Statement it is not required to repeat the bind values if the names are equal.
For example this **Anonymous Block** is working:

```
DECLARE
  a NUMBER := 4;
  b NUMBER := 7;
  plsql_block VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  plsql_block := 'BEGIN calc_stats(:x, :x, :y, :x); END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING a, b;  -- calc_stats(a, a, b, a)
END;
/
```

But this `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING a, b;` does not work **inside a Procedure**.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work? Because I am executing multiple queries in a loop and each query has multiple same bindings.

Comment: @ManiSankar what do you mean? Please open a question with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have referenced the column name through bind variable is not a preferred method as Nichoas pointed out. What you tried is called as native dynamic SQL using 'cleverer' bind variables.

In this method, you need to bind every parameter X times since you use it X times because they are all treated as separate variables.

Read more on [binding to dynamic SQL.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:104931400346587790)

Answer (score 1):

@ethan and @ManiSankar I too had a same problem in my scenario as well. I solved this using some kind of brute force techinque. What i have done is

Before this
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query INTO col_value USING  col_name ;

I have added replace condition in my code by replacing parameter with the required value then called "Execute Immediate" without "using" clause

```
lv_query := replace(lv_query, ':1',col_name);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query INTO col_value;
```

I don't know this is optimal one but served purpose for what i am expecting..

Please advice if this one recommended or not...