# oracle execute immediate using reference to multiple variables

Tags: oracle, rest, execute-immediate

I'm using Oracle Rest Data Services to build an app.

I can easily read & write with something like this `GET http://example.com/foo/bar` that runs query `SELECT * FROM bar` or

`POST http://example.com/foo/bar
{
  "first": "a'b",
  "second": "c,d"
}`

that runs query `INSERT INTO bar (first, second) VALUES (:first, :second)`

Where query parameters are bound from request body.

Now, I'd like to build a route that run a dynamic query.

I can do that with one binding param, eg.:

`POST http://example.com/foo/query
{
  "query": "DELETE FROM bar WHERE first = :param",
  "param": "a'b"
}`

that runs query

`BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING :param; END;`

But I don't know how to do it with multiple params. For eg.

`POST http://example.com/foo/query
{
  "query": "DELETE FROM bar WHERE first = :first AND second = :second",
  "bindings": "first,second",
  "first": "a'b",
  "second": "c,d"
}`

The query should be something like

`DECLARE
  params ...? -- (params variable should set USING list from :bindings request param) 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING params; 
END;`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's only a small change from your previous example. See [this example from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-30ADFC05-8DFB-4C8A-831D-426C2E97F217__CHDIEFCJ) for more info.

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING :first, :second; END;
```

As a warning, the bind variable names in the query don't need to match the names in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE block - they're evaluated in the order they occur, not by name. So in this example:

```
:query := 'DELETE FROM bar WHERE first = :a and second = :b';
execute immediate :query using :my_var1, :my_var2;
```

The value of pl/sql variable `my_var1` is assigned to sql bind variable `a` since they're both the first ones. It can get more complicated [if you want to repeat variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899011/using-execute-immediate-with-multiple-same-bind-arguments)... but I think that's enough to answer your question.